# PyCharm running Python file always opens a new console

Tags: python, console, pycharm

I initially started learning Python in Spyder, but decided to switch to PyCharm recently, hence I'm learning PyCharm with a Spyder-like mentality.

I'm interested in running a file in the Python console, but every time I rerun this file, it will run under a newly opened Python console. This can become annoying after a while, as there will be multiple Python consoles open which basically all do the same thing but with slight variations.

I would prefer to just have one single Python console and run an entire file within that single console. Would anybody know how to change this? Perhaps the mindset I'm using isn't very PyCharmic?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a specific option in PyCharm 2018.2+: **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Use existing console for "Run with Python console"**.

**Run with Python console** is an option you have enabled in the Run Configuration. Disable it if you don't need a Python console after a script execution:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, I was able to do what you proposed but I had to restart Pycharm recently and since then activating these options isn't working. In the settings/console I have ticked ' use existing console for ''Run with python console'' ' and in the edit/debug configuration I have ticked 'Run with python console', but Pycharm still opens a new console everytime I run the code (Maj + F10) or when I right click and choose 'Run file in console'. Any idea about what might be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @MorningGlory I also have that problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @azureai I am currently using Pycharm 2019.2.3 and the Run with Python console will now run on the same python window when you execute the code... but after a year of not using it I've become used to running opening a new console everytime I execute the script (lol). If I want to rerun a script on the same console, I will simply press rerun (ctrl + f5), this has the disadvantage of erasing all the variables and starting from scratch, but that's fine with me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 15):

Hi: If you are looking for re running the code again in the same python console everytime then you have to check the respective box in the Project settings as shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: this is really helpful along with a shortcut to run file in console

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Pycharm is still opening a new console everytime. I am using pycharm community 2021.1

Answer (score 2):

To allow only one instance to run, go to "Run" in the top bar, then "Edit Configurations...". Finally, check "Single instance only" at the right side. This will run only one instance and restart every time you run.

Comment: In PyCharm 2022.2.4 the option in that menu now reads "Allow parallel run"

Answer (score 0):

One console is one instance of Python being run on your system. If you want to run different variations of code within the same Python kernel, you can highlight the code you want to run and then choose the `run` option (Alt+Shift+F10 default).

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to *Rerun* the program.

Simply open and navigate to currently running app with:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (Windows)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (Mac)

And then *rerun* it with:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Windows)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Mac)

**Another option:**

Show actions popup:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Windows)
- <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Mac)

And type *Rerun ...*, IDE then hint you with desired action, and call it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is the last option in this window; check it and it should work.

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console

[image]