# Prevent "run with Python Console" by default

Tags: pycharm

Since a recent update of the PyCharm IDE, I find that all my configurations have "Run with Python Console" turned on by default. This is annyoing, because the open sessions need a lot of memory and they have to be closed manually.

I know how [to turn off "Run with Python Console" case by case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831152/pycharm-running-python-file-always-opens-a-new-console), but that's annoying as well. I would like the default to be not running with the Python Console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Run" menu, go to "Edit configurations". You find a link "Edit configuration templates" in the bottom left corner.

[image: Edit configuration templates]

There, choose the "Python" template and uncheck "Run with Python Console".

[image: Edit template]

This setting is global, i.e. it will also apply for new projects, not only new configurations in the current project.